# How to remove special characters from excel(xlsx) file using python3?

Tags: python, string

How to extract all the rows from excel file using python3 and remove special characters?

> Table.xlsx

[Tablle.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIwZk.jpg)

```
import xlrd 

loc = ("Table.xlsx") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

print(sheet.row_values(1))
```

> Expected Output:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYqH3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a word document. It may do the same for you...

Function I used:

```
import re

def removeSpecialCharacters(cellValue):
    text=re.sub(r"[\r\n\t\x07\x0b]", "", cellValue)
    return text
```

Afterwards, I used this for the values:

```
character = table.Cell(Row = 1, Column = 1).Range.Text
character = removeSpecialCharacters(character)
```

You may also use a for loop for your solution as well.